# how to assemble vectors into matrix using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

I want to assemble a matrix from 5 vectors using a `for` loop in Matlab.
How can I do that? Or is there a simple alternative to do the same?

Here's an example: I have 5 vectors:

```
A = [1 2 3]
B = [1 2 3]
C = [1 2 3]
D = [1 2 3]
E = [1 2 3]
```

I want to create a matrix `Z` of size 3 x 5 from these vectors.

Comment: As it stands your question is meaningless. Please add *a lot* more detail

Comment: ok. I have 5 vectors
A = [ 1 2 3]
B = [ 1 2 3]
C = [ 1 2 3]
D = [ 1 2 3]
E = [ 1 2 3]
I want to create a matrix "Z" from this vectors of size 3 x 5.

How can I do it using for loop?

Comment: What do you mean with "assemble"? It's no defined operation. Are you looking for `vcat` or `hcat`?

Comment: By assemble, I mean to formulate a matrix, the matrix should take values from the vectors.

Comment: @user3270090 Google concatenating matrices in Matlab.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear what he's asking. He has 5 vectors and wants a matrix with all of them inside. He wants to do it with a for loop or a simple alternative. He's obviously very new to Matlab and hasn't even tried looking at the "Getting Started with Matlab" help section, which arguably questions his motivation, but it doesn't make the question unclear. Just look at it from a general, non-Matlab perspective. I'll also edit his comment into the question, which should make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops are generally a bad idea in Matlab. Use vectorized syntax:

```
Z = [A;B;C;D;E]'; %'// vertical concatenation (5x3), then transpose to get 3x5
>> size(Z)
ans =

     3     5
```

You can also transpose the vectors first and then concatenate them:

```
Z = [A' B' C' D' E']; %'// this comment is a syntax highlighting hotfix
>> size(Z)
ans =

     3     5
```

If you really insist on using a `for` loop, here's how you would do that:

```
Z(3,5) = 0; %// preallocate a 3x5 numerical matrix
for i=1:3
    Z(i,1) = A(i);
    Z(i,2) = B(i);
    Z(i,3) = C(i);
    Z(i,4) = D(i);
    Z(i,5) = E(i);
end
```

But it really makes no sense at all to do it this way...